# "new" keyword in Java(Android) :D

Tags: java, android, oop

I have read some reference's and i think i understood the usage the "new" keyword in OOP languange (but i don't!)

So i can't understand this line of code, i got it from the tut's in [thenewboston](http://www.thenewboston.com) :

```
ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
ourBrow.setWebViewClient(new OurViewClient());
```

So the `setWebViewClient();` method requires a WebViewClient in it's params. The think that i don't understand is, why we need to add the "new" keyword here?
NOTE that `OurViewClient()` is a class that we made and extended by `WebViewClient`.

Sorry, if my way to ask the question is making you confuse, coz i also confuse now @_@

Thanks All! :D

NOTE : English is not my native languange, so sorry if i made some mistake's :D

Comment: `OurViewClient` is a class, and `new OurViewClient()` is an instance of that class.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad -- I think OP is asking why `OurViewClient()` (with parentheses but without the keyword) isn't the way to invoke the constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OurViewClient` is the class that you made.  `OurViewClient()` is a *constructor* for that class which takes 0 parameters.  And the `setWebViewClient()` method requires a `WebViewClient` *instance* as its parameter.

So the `new` operator effectively allocates a new instance of the `OurViewClient` class and then invokes the default 0-parameter constructor on that instance, returning the created object.  Using `new` is the only way you can create an instance of an `Object` in Java, barring more advanced topics like reflection or using things like `sun.misc.Unsafe` and also some exceptions centered around built-in types/autoboxing (e.g. `String s = "str";` and `Integer num = 7;`).

Note that the following code is essentially equivalent to the code that you have:

```
WebViewClient client = new OurViewClient();
ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
ourBrow.setWebViewClient(client);
```

Also note that the following are *invalid*:

```
WebViewClient client = OurViewClient();  //can't invoke a constructor without using 'new'
WebViewClient client = OurViewClient;    //can't assign the class
WebViewClient client;  //valid syntax, but 'client' will be null
```

Answer (score 4):

The `new` keyword creates a new instance of a certain class. If it's written between the brackets of a method function it only means you don't want a reference to the created object in the thread you are working on.

It's only a shorter way to say

```
ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
OurViewClient temp = new OurViewClient();
ourBrow.setWebViewClient(temp);
```

with `temp` a temporal value. In most cases this means that the method will execute some default behaviour.

There are a lot of those "tricks" in programming languages. But you could compare it to algebra. It's only a matter of symbolic manipulation. With the piece of code above I illustrate the algebraic principle "give the child a name" (I don't know if that's an english expression, my mother tongue is dutch). There are a lot of other examples of this principe for instance `foo(4+5)`. This actually means that you create a temporary integer that stores 4+5=9 and then calls the `foo` method.

Answer (score 3):

The `new` operator creates an instance of the class. Without the `new` keyword in the code that you posted, the argument to `setWebViewClient` would not be a legal Java expression (unless `OurViewClient()` were some method visible at that point in the code). In particular, it would *not* be a call to the default constructor for class `OurViewClient`. Constructors are called by using the `new` keyword. That's just how the language is designed.

Answer (score 3):

`new` instantiates an object of your class.  A WebViewClient is an abstract idea, it describes the specifications for an object, but it doesn't give you something concrete to work with.  An object lets you work with a specific, concrete, *instance* of a class.

You could do the following to make it clearer:

```
OurViewClient ourClient = new OurViewClient();
ourBrow.setWebViewClient(ourClient);
```

Or also:

```
WebViewClient ourClient = new OurViewClient();
ourBrow.setWebViewClient(ourClient);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a class (`OurViewClient`, in your example) like a blueprint.

Just because a blueprint exists, it doesn't mean a building exists. You only have the plans to make one.

So when you use the "`new`" keyword, you're doing the actual construction.